# Possibility/nature of SSB in systems with long-range interaction not mediated by gauge fields

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, field-theory, symmetry-breaking

Is there any real Condensed Matter system modelled by a Hamiltonian with long-range interaction (except those mediated by any gauge fields) such as long-range spin-spin interaction that displays the phenomenon of spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB)? If such a system(s) exist, does its spectrum still contain gapless Goldstone mode(s)?

Please note, I know that in the presence of gauge fields such Goldstone modes gets eaten up by the gauge field and becomes massive. This is what happens in the case of superconductivity theory. That's not the premise of the question here.

**Important references**

$1.$ [Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking and Nambu–Goldstone Bosons
in Quantum Many-Body Systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5212)

$2.$ [Mass/Energy Gap Associated to Symmetry Breaking: A Generalized Goldstone Theorem for Long-Range Interactions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-5221-1_24)